# How do i get labels from mirror with empty values

Tags: swift, struct, initialization, mirror

What i want to do is when i start the app, save all the names (in userDefault) of the constants from all models. I plan on doing it with a function looking something like:

```
    public static func setup(models: [Codable]) {
            models.forEach { (model) in
                let mirr = Mirror.init(reflecting: model)
                mirr.children.map({
                    UserDefaults.save("\(type(of: model))+\($0.label!)")})
            }
    }
```

Please note that i'm not finished yet.

What i know of there are 3 solutions to using this method. As the mirror wont show me labels unless the variable / constant has an actual value. It becomes really ugly and i wonder if i can do some work around because current you call it like this.

Scenario A:

```
public struct Testing: Codable {
    let name: String = ""
    let sex: String = ""
}

setup(models: [Testing()])
```

Scenario B:

```
public struct testing: Codable {
    let name: String
    let sex: String
}

setup(models: [Testing(name: "", sex: "")])
```

Scenario C:

```
public struct testing: Codable {
    let name: String
    let sex: String

    init(name: String =  "", sex: String = "") {
        self.name = name
        self.sex = sex
    }
}

setup(models: [Testing()])
```

So basically what i want to do is:

```
public struct testing: Codable {
    let name: String
    let sex: String
}

setup(models: [Testing()])
// or 
setup(models: [Testing.self])
```

Or kinda anything that wont force me to init the values.
I guess it can't be done, but maybe someone have some hack out there that work...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using Codable if you're not dealing with JSON type? You can simply create a struct with init as per requirement.

Comment: I will use the codable in a later stage. And as i mentioned i don't want to create that kind of init as it is ugly. and sort of makes codable redundant

Comment: Well, what's ugly in that by the way?

Comment: I dont want to create a init method that is used once for only this purpose. Imagine having 10 structs with 10-15 values.. that is a lot of lines that we wont use.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply update your `setup(models:)` method to,

```
public func setup(models: [Codable]) {
    let arr: [String] = models.compactMap {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: $0)
        if let name = mirror.children.first(where: { $0.label == "name" }) {
            let value = "\(type(of: $0))+\(name.value)"
            return value
        }
        return nil
    }
    UserDefaults.standard.set(arr, forKey: "Names")
}
```

Comment: As the setup function need to take `[Codable]` and not `[Testing]` it wont work?

Comment: Why will it not work? Are you making `setup` method generic for all the `Codable` types that contain `name` as a property?

Comment: Yes it's generic, but no, all of them doesn't contain name. it's random.. it can be any attributes at all.

Comment: If it doesn't, then how will you get name from all of them?

Comment: create a mirror `let mirror = Mirror(modelı[0])`
loop through it's children `mirror.children.foreach {$0.label}` I wrote how i do it in the question

Comment: Sorry i changed title from "names" to "label" to make it less confusing

Comment: Still not looking for the names. I want to take a model with any and multiple variables / constants and store them all. This `Testing`  contains name and sex, while another might contain strenght and stamina and a third of luck and dexterity

Comment: Then why don't you convert your object to data and save it as whole? Why store all the properties individually?

Comment: Becausei need the variable names as keys in a later stage

Comment: Then in later stages you can use Mirror for that. But for saving in UserDefaults won't do any good.

Comment: Then im not following, how should i store the Data object in that case and how to use Mirror on it if it still doesn't have values assigned?